# Jquery - multiple checkbox and multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 check box when i select anyone of the check box need to display the respective check box and text box.

input type="checkbox" id="acheck[]" value='name'

input type="textbox" id="productfield" value=' '

jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $("#productfield").css("display","none");

        $("#acheck").click(function(){

                if ($("#acheck").is(":checked"))
                {

                    $("#productfield").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                else
                {     

                    $("#productfield").fadeOut("slow");
                }       

      });

});
```

Comment: You should make clearer what you really want to do

Comment: And I let you know when you ask a question.

Comment: You're using jQuery, you're making a form that contains text fields and checkboxes. That's all I understand here... What do you want to do ?

Comment: You've asked two questions on this site so far, both of them basically boil down to "Write me some code". Please show a bit of initiative and try to solve the problem yourself before asking for help. People can tell you where you went wrong, or suggest general improvements, and you'll probably learn more and save yourself time and goodwill in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question, but I guess you want something to appear when you click the checkbox?  This should get you started.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #appear_div { display: none; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#appear').click(function() { $('#appear_div').show(); });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="appear">
  <div id="appear_div">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">Check me <input type="text" id="text1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```